# How to use != when there are duplicate entries?

Tags: mysql, sql

[image]

From the above table, I want to select the user_id 's who are not in project_id '1'.

If I use project_id != 1, it eliminates user_id 's in project_id 1. But, if the user_id is present in another project_id (like users 8 and 10 in the table), those users will be present in the results. How can I avoid this?

Comment: So you mean you want rows where user_id never been in project_id = 1? NOT EXISTS is what you want.

Comment: `select user_id 
from table 
where user_id not in (select user_id from table where project_id = 1)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use inner select query for this

```
  Select * from table 
      where user_id not in  
    (Select user_id from table where project_id = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `not in` and a subquery

```
select *
from MyTable
where user_id not in
(select user_id 
 from MyTable
 where project_id = 1)
```

Or a `not exists`

```
select m1.*
from MyTable m1
where not exists
(select m2.user_id 
 from MyTable m2
 where m2.project_id = 1
 and m2.user_id = m1.user_id)
```

Comment: What happens if user_id NULL is returned from the sub-query?

Answer (score 0):

Checkout if it is also helpful: using `MINUS`

```
select user_id from mytable a
minus
select user_id from mytable b where b.project_id = 1
```